# Apache Redirect Permanent - Query String

Tags: regex, apache

I have a website, where I want to redirect all requests with a query against my domain, to the home page.

```
http://www.example.com/?ref=something_query_string
http://www.example.com/?ref=something_else_query_string
http://www.example.com/?id=something_query_string
```

all the variations of the above should redirect (301) to

```
http://www.example.com
```

and any URL with query string after a URI e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/some_uri_in_middler/?ref=something_query_string
```

should not be redirected.

What I have tried so far

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/$ / [R=302,L]
```

But this fails as it's causing an infinite redirect loop :(

Any help is greatly appreciated!